# Get shortTimeDate from Unix format (C#)

Tags: c#, datetime, time, unix-timestamp, converters

I have time input data as below:

```
1536271200
1536184800
1536098400
1536012000
1535925600
```

I made quick Unix TimeConverter:

```
public static DateTime Converter(double ts)
{
        DateTime org= new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        org = org.AddSeconds(ts);
        org = org.ToLocalTime();

        return org;
}
```

but after convert it return me date as below:

```
2018-09-10 00:00:00
2018-09-07 00:00:00
2018-09-06 00:00:00
2018-09-05 00:00:00
2018-09-04 00:00:00
2018-09-03 00:00:00
```

How to get shortDateFormat (YYYY-MM-DD)?

Comment: `string formattedDate = Converter(someValue).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: org.ToShortDateString(); should do or org.Date should also work

Comment: FOr reference you can refer this bog : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: DateTime itself has no format. You need to format it into a string if you want a specific formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.ToString(format)` to get what ever format you want, and in this case it would be `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`:

```
public static string Converter(double ts)
{
        DateTime org= new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        org = org.AddSeconds(ts);
        org = org.ToLocalTime();

        return org.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

and of course the function's return type must be string.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting confused between a DateTime object, and a "text string that looks like a date"

Your DateTime object holds the instant in time that the date is. You can make it into a text string that looks like whatever you want by using .ToString() and a format string:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Or you can use one of the provided shortcut methods for standard format strings, like .ToShortDateString()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2

Ultimately, what you need to appreciate is that you're complaining "my date has a time tacked on the end" -> datetimes always have a time component. There is no date in this world, your birthday, your grad day, new year's day etc that does NOT have a time associated with it.

Everything happens at a time, on a date.

When you told your program to print those dates out to the console, it included the times (all midnight) because that's what your system does by default. If you want to print them out without the times, specify a format that doesn't include time placeholders.. It is in the process of preparing data for display, that we choose what we want to see